# toggle image via onclick issue javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle between two images I have in a folder via an onclick function. Currently my code does not toggle the image and I am getting no console errors, so I don't know why the toggle is not occurring. my folders look like this:

```
program-01
    program01.index
    program01javascript
        program01script.js
    program01css
    images
        LightOff.png
        LightOn.png
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="images/LightOff.png" id="light" onclick="DateTime(); imageSwap();" />
    <p id="date_time"></p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function imageSwap(){
    var img = document.getElementById("light") ;
    if (img.src == "images/LightOff.png"){
        img.src = "images/LightOn.png";
    } else {
        img.src = "images/LightOff.png";
    }
}
```

I believe it has have something to do with my file path and or something to do with the .src property, but unsure of exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Try adding a backslash at the beginning of the image url. `"/images/LightOff.png"` and `"/images/LightOn.png"`

Comment: When the page loads, does it load `LightOff.png` ?

Comment: @Sachin yes the image appears when the page is loaded

Comment: @Brian that gives me an error of image not found

Comment: Does the image exist on the server? Can you type in the same URL in the browser and it comes up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ?

> `img.src` will return absolute url, I would suggest you to play with the flags instead of image `src`

```
var status = false;
function imageSwap() {
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    if (!status) {
        img.src = "images/LightOn.png";
        status = true;
    } else {
        img.src = "images/LightOff.png";
        status = false;
    }
}
```

> Or doing it your way, use `getAttribute`

```
function imageSwap(){
    var img = document.getElementById("light") ;
    if (img.getAttribute('src') == "images/LightOff.png"){
        img.src = "images/LightOn.png";
    } else {
        img.src = "images/LightOff.png";
    }
}
```